# Using LINQ with references from other entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
rate = Db.PaymentRates_House
         .AsNoTracking()
         .Where(h => h.LocationCityName.Contains(mappings.FirstOrDefault().CityName)
             && h.LocationCountryName == mappings.FirstOrDefault().Location.Province.Name
             && h.AreaCodeTypeId == areaType)
```

Since I don't know how exactly LINQ caches things, I was wondering about:

- Is my use of `.AsNoTracking()` appropriate?
- Should I remove the `mappings.FirstOrDefault().Location.Province.Name` and replace it with a separate variable?
- Are there any other suggestions to make this LINQ query better?

**Edit:**

The code that prepends the code above is as follows:

```
var mappings = Db.MercerCityMappings.Where(x => x.LocationId == locationId);
if (mappings.Any())
{
    // above code
}
```

Comment: What is `mappings` in your code example? Another query?

Comment: Be careful, if `mappings.FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`, an exception will be thrown when attempting to accesss the property `Location`.

Comment: I added the code that defines `mappings` and checks for `.Any()`. Thanks.

Comment: @Abbas: Actually, in Entity Framework, this will just get converted to a SQL query, so no exception would be thrown--it'll just resolve to null.